# showing last query result in view

Tags: database, codeigniter

I want to see the my last query result in view but I can not do it.please guide me.
I selected the records from database and want to show it view but the result of my query is false however I test this query in mysql and it returns the records.I need to see my last query result how can I do it?

*model:*

```
function pub_article(){
    $where=array('public'=>'1');
    $query=$this->db->get_where('article',$where);

    echo $this->db->last_query(); 
    exit;

    if($query->num_rows() >0 )
        return $query->result();
    else 
       return false;
}
```

*cotroller*

```
$data['pub']=$this->mymodel->pub_article();
$this->load->view('first',$data);
```

*view*

```
foreach($pub->result() as $row){
    echo $row->title;
}
```

I write echo $this->db->last_query();exit; after get_where.Is it the right place?how can I see it in view?

Answer (score 0):

"exit" takes you out of your function pub_article(), so nothing else runs.

Remove that line

Answer (score 0):

U are using exit to terminate ur script... remove the line and change code to this..

model:

```
function pub_article(){
    $where=array('public'=>'1');
    $query=$this->db->get_where('article',$where);

    if($query->num_rows() >0 )
        return $query->result();
    else 
       return false;
}
```

now to see your last query result u can do this .. in your controller

```
function your_controller {
   $data['pub'] = $this->my_model->pub_article();
   echo '<pre>';var_dump($data);exit;   //use this line.. comment this line to run script again
   echo '<pre>';print_r($data);exit;   //or this line ..  comment this line to run script again

   $this->load->view('first',$data);
}
```